# instead of trigger not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an application where two column could be populated from a number of different applications; one, the XY location (stgeometry) is determined by the application: two, the XY location is typed by the user into separate x and y columns.

I've come up with the following trigger to populate the X and Y column in scenario one, and to populate the shape column in scenario 2. It seems to be looping and not populating either column. Where did I go wrong?

```
    ALTER trigger [dbo].[update_location_geometry]
    --Trigger to allow non-gis input of XY data in X_Coord and Y_Coord columns, yet still populate the WKB
    --shape column with coordinate using 26917 EPSG so that new location will be available to the gis without
    -- additional user intervention
    on [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS]
    instead of insert as
    begin
--this block populates stgeometry.shape col with user-input XY and is not using the application to
-- determine xy
    if exists (select top 1 * from inserted where shape is not null)

    update dbo.tbl_locations
    set SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                        CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917)
    WHERE (UPDATE(X_Coord) OR UPDATE(Y_Coord))
                 AND objectId IN (SELECT ins.objectId FROM inserted ins) 


  --this block populates the XY column from stgeometry.shape when the application calculated XY   
    update dbo.tbl_locations
    set X_Coord = SHAPE.STX,Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY 
    WHERE (UPDATE(Shape))
                 AND objectId IN (SELECT ins.objectId FROM inserted ins)
    End
```

Tried this as well, still looping:

```
  ALTER trigger [dbo].[update_location_geometry]
    --Trigger to allow non-gis input of XY data in X_Coord and Y_Coord columns, yet still populate the WKB
    --shape column with coordinate using 26917 EPSG so that new location will be available to the gis without
    -- additional user intervention
    on [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS]
    instead of insert as -- Aaron changed update to insert here


IF UPDATE(X_Coord) OR UPDATE(Y_Coord)

Begin
update dbo.tbl_locations
set SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917)

END
IF UPDATE(Shape) 
Begin
update dbo.tbl_locations
set X_Coord = SHAPE.STX,Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY 

End
```

And this produces syntax error:

```
instead of update as

IF update (X_Coord) OR UPDATE(Y_Coord) AND objectId IN (SELECT ins.objectId FROM inserted ins)

Begin
update dbo.tbl_locations
set SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917)

END
IF UPDATE(Shape)AND objectId IN (SELECT ins.objectId FROM inserted ins)
Begin
update dbo.tbl_locations
set X_Coord = SHAPE.STX,Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY 

End


Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_location_geometry, Line 10
Invalid column name 'objectId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure update_location_geometry, Line 18
Invalid column name 'objectId'.
```

Final Solution:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_location_geometry] ON [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS BEGIN     
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE SHAPE IS NOT NULL)     
BEGIN         
INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid, loc_name)             
SELECT SHAPE, X_Coord = SHAPE.STX,Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY,objectid, loc_name            
FROM inserted;     
END     
ELSE     
BEGIN         
INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid,loc_name)             
SELECT SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT('
+ CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' 
+ CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917),
X_Coord, Y_Coord,objectid,loc_name
FROM inserted;
END
END
```

Example of insert:

```
INSERT INTO [ATBI].[dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS]
           ([OBJECTID]
           ,[X_Coord]
           ,[Y_Coord]
           ,Loc_Name,
           Notes)

     VALUES
           (368
           ,324999.997
           ,3970798.079
           ,'blahblah'
           ,'notes of test')
```

Production table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS](
    [OBJECTID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FCategory] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [MapMethod] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [HError] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MapSource] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SourceDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [EditDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Site_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Meta_MID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [X_Coord] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [Y_Coord] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [Coord_Units] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Coord_System] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [UTM_Zone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Accuracy_Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Unit_Code] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
    [Loc_Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Loc_Type] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [Updated_Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Loc_Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Datum] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Watershed] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [StreamName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NHDReachCode] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [TOPO_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Trail] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Road] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Elevation] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [LAT] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [LON] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [Year_] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [County] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [IsExtant] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [IsSenstive] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [Eco_Notes] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EcoGroup] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ELCode] [smallint] NULL,
    [Validation] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LocationDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LocationDirections] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [VerbatimLocation] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PlaceName] [nvarchar](75) NULL,
    [SHAPE] [geometry] NULL,
    [Location_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TBL_LOCATIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OBJECTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [g2_ck] CHECK  (([SHAPE].[STSrid]=(26917)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS] CHECK CONSTRAINT [g2_ck]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__TBL_LOCAT__Globa__12C8C788]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Location_ID]
GO
```

Comment: Your second attempt is trying to update the whole table; there is no correlation to the inserted table at all. Unless your table is empty (otherwise you would notice the entire table has been updated), I'll again suggest that perhaps you are running `UPDATE` statements and this trigger isn't firing because it's an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an insert trigger, does checking `UPDATE` make sense? Did you mean to make it an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger instead of `INSTEAD OF INSERT`?

Also, assuming it should be an `UPDATE` trigger, I would usually check this way as opposed to the `WHERE` clause:

```
IF UPDATE(X_Coord) OR UPDATE(Y_Coord)
BEGIN
    -- first update without first where clause
END

IF UPDATE(Shape)
BEGIN
    -- second update without first where clause
END
```

Ok so I was stuck on the fact that you were trying to use an instead of insert trigger for an update. The problem is that an instead of trigger requires you to still perform the insert operation yourself, because the trigger is running **instead of** the insert. Try this (note that if there are other columns being inserted along with `SHAPE` or `X_Coord`/`Y_Coord`, you'll need to pull those from `inserted` as well):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_location_geometry]
ON [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(ObjectID, SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord)
        SELECT ObjectID, SHAPE, X_Coord = SHAPE.STX, Y_Coord = SHAPE.STY 
        FROM inserted WHERE SHAPE IS NOT NULL;

    INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(ObjectID, SHAPE, X_Coord, Y_Coord)
        SELECT ObjectID, SHAPE=Geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(' 
          + CAST(X_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' 
          + CAST(Y_Coord AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 26917), 
          X_Coord, Y_Coord 
        FROM inserted WHERE SHAPE IS NULL;
END
GO
```

I tried this with the following `INSERT` statements and they populated the table just fine:

```
INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(ObjectID, X_Coord, Y_Coord) 
    SELECT 1, 20, 30;

INSERT dbo.TBL_Locations(ObjectID, Shape) 
    SELECT 2, 0x25690000010C00000000000034400000000000003E30;
```

Comment: When I add back 'AND objectId IN (SELECT ins.objectId FROM inserted ins)' I get lines of errors. I'm definitely missing some very obvious syntax here. been staring at this for hours. The source of the data in this particular situation is always inserts.

Comment: yes, you were correct, if other columns are being populated by the user or the application at insert, their absence from the trigger causes it to fail. Would it be too messy, performance-wise, to globally include all columns in the trigger? Users have the choice of populating none or all of the others at edit time, in addition to the soon-to-be written triggers that use stwithin to automate a lot (e.g. what state is the point in?)Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, if you need to perform these calculations before the insert, then add the other columns that a user might specify (though I still don't know what "fail" means; usually helpful to post an actual error message so that we are talking the same). If they can optionally specify or not specify required columns, then you'll need to use `COALESCE` to populate them with default or token values (or change those columns from `NULL` to `NOT NULL` if you want them to be able to leave them as `NULL`). Though you might consider testing just the update functionality with an AFTER trigger instead.

Comment: that's tricky one to anwer...there is no error-message per say: when using the application (ArcGIS) to drop new points all over the map (inserts) and not attributting any of the columns, it works fine. However, when using a sql insert statment, any columns that I populate which are not contained in the trigger statement...do not show up in a query. All columns in question are set to nullable.

Comment: Ok, so again you just need to add all of the other columns to the `INSERT` statement and pull the values from `inserted`. If they haven't been specified, they'll just end up `NULL` - no harm, no foul. You will need to list the other columns individually though, I don't suggest you try to do anything with shorthand like `SELECT *` because it won't work with the trigger I've provided.